# Positivity and negativity of polarised light

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, double-slit-experiment, polarization

Are there any positive vertically polarised light and negative vertically polarised light, or its just vertically polarised light which is there if the light is vertically polarised?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never met the term "positive vertically polarised" or "negative vertically polarised". I'd have been surprised to do so, as the so-called *direction* of polarisation of a wave isn't really a direction but an *alignment*. For example a wave oscillating up and down has a vertical alignment to its oscillations. A wave oscillating left and right has a horizontal alignment.

[I am grateful to JEB for introducing me to 'alignment'; using it instead of misusing 'direction' removes one source of confusion.]

Comment: Note that, for a beam of spin-half particles like electrons or neutrons, "up vertical" and "down vertical" are in fact orthogonal spin states. The difference has to do with the way that a spinor like the electron transforms under rotations, which is different from a spin-one "vector" particle like the photon.

Answer (score 1):

Light has an electric and a magnetic field component. Both are perpendicular to each other and perpendicular to the direction of propagation. Each field component oscillates its field strength from a maximum value through zero to the negative maximum value and back again. It is not possible to generate only the positive or the negative half-wave.